# How to compare iterators content in unit test?

Tags: java, junit, assertj

I have two `java.util.Scanner` objects. `Scanner` class implements `Iterator<String>`. I wanna compare scanners and have easy ability to see what lines are different.

Currently I use AssertJ soft assertions in this way

```
@Rule
JUnitSoftAssertions softly = new JUnitSoftAssertions();
...
Scanner actual = ...
Scanner expected = ...

int i = 0;
while (actual.hasNext() && expected.hasNext()) {
  softly.assertThat(actual.next()).as("line %s", i++).isEqualTo(expected.next());
}
```

This code insn't perfect but whether is ability in AssertJ to do this in one assertion?

I see static `IterableAssert<ELEMENT> assertThat(Iterator<? extends ELEMENT> actual)` method in `Assertions` class but can't see appropriate check method in `IterableAssert`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs say:

```
softly.assertThat(actual).containsExactlyElementsOf(expected);
```

See: http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/core/api/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractIterableAssert.html#containsExactlyElementsOf(java.lang.Iterable)

So, you could create a custom `Iterable` that returns your scanners

```
public class ScannerIterable implements Iterable<String> {

    private Scanner scanner;

    public ScanerIterable(Scanner scanner) {
        this.scanner = scanner;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<String> iterator() {
        return scanner;
    }
}
```

This could be made generic, so it could take in any kind of `Iterator`.

Comment: Ha-ha... I saw this method but it doesn't work as `expected` Scanner implements `Iterator<String>` but `containsExactlyElementsOf` method requires `Iterable<? extends ELEMENT>` as a parameter.

Comment: @Jeramy It's slightly different as I expected but... thanks!

Comment: It's worth mentioning that `containsExactlyElementsOf` eagerly loads `expected` to an array (and thus to memory). It might be problematic for large iterators. And it's not fully equivalent to what the OP is doing as workaround.